# Debugger does not stop at production code breakpoints

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, intellij-idea, jasmine

I have nodejs module which I unit test with jasmine-ts [0.3.0] by running `jasmine-ts --config=spec/support/jasmine.json`.

My intention is that I want to run some unit test and stop at breakpoint which is inside the function that I am testing. Unfortunately debugger stops only inside unit tests, but not in production code.

***What could be the issue?***

More information about my tries.

1. Typescript recompilation on changes is on in my Intellij IDEA 2020.1. I can recognise that it works correctly as when I change some typescript file in production code, I can see the changes in corresponding Javascript file in `dist` folder.
2. If I run my module then I can stop at breakpoints as well.
3. The weird thing is that I can stop at the breakpoint in production code while executing unit tests in another module where `mocha` is used and is run like this: `npx mocha -r ts-node/register test/**/*.test.ts`.

Thoughts what could be wrong.

1. Dependencies might not work correctly together. I was recently updating the libraries to the latest version, but noticed, that `jasmine-ts` requires `ts-node` less than 8, so currently I have the following versions in my package.json:

   ```
   "devDependencies": {
       "jasmine": "3.3.1",
       "jasmine-ts": "^0.3.0",
       "ts-node": "7.0.1",
       "nyc": "^13.0.1",
       "typescript": "^3.8.3",
       "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.8",
       "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.0",
       "jasmine-reporters": "^2.3.2"
   }
   ```
2. Source mapping might be broken. I have checked some `*.js.map` files and it seems like they are pointing to correct `*.ts` files, so, don't know what to check more there.
3. I was thinking if typescript configuration might influence as well, but unclear for me exactly how. Anyway, this is my tsconfig.json:

   ```
   {
   "compilerOptions": {
       "strict": false,
       "target": "es2015",
       "sourceMap": true,
       "module": "commonjs",
       "outDir": "./dist",
       "moduleResolution": "node"
   },
   "include": [
       "src/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "exclude": [
       "./spec/**/*.ts",
       "./node_modules/**/*.ts"
   ]
   }
   ```
4. Something is definitely wrong. When I want to see the coverage that I run with nyc npm test, I see Javascript files, however, it should be Typescript. But I assume that it might be a different issue, but maybe not...

Any hints to resolve the issue?:)

**Update:**

One way to fix this issue is to clean up the code from Intellij IDEA and other files that might influence to the stable work by removing the project completely from the computer and clone it again. By this action it helped me to stop at breakpoints in other modules that use jasmine, however my module still have weird state as I come to the production code at some point, but not in order. I assume seeing some errors regarding promises, but I don't.

Comment: Is the production code minimized?  How are you setting the breakpoint in the first place?

Comment: Well, I have tried it in different places. I don't really understand the second question, I am using Intellij IDEA where i click to the left side of the line and get a red dot. The fact is that these breakpoints were working before let's say like 1-2 weeks ago. I am now starting to think if Intellij IDEA update to 2020.1 broke it, but I still doubt that.

Comment: is your production code instrumented for coverage? This might break the source maps, causing issues like yours. If this is not the case, please ccontact support, providing a sample app the issue can be reproduced with. It shouldn't be a proprietary code, just a dummy app with similar setup

Comment: Maybe I will create a dummy app and see if it behaves similar.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had the *Recompile on changes* checkbox **on** in the *Language & Frameworks -> Typescript*.

This brings the functionality that for each `.ts` file there will be generated `.js` file, but in my case all `js` compiled files must be in `dist` directory that I specify in `tsconfig` file. My assumption is that during debug session debugger didn't know which file to take or was taking the wrong one. Setting *Recompile to changes* to **off** solved the problem.

Even though I still have weird behaviour as debugger comes to the production code earlier than expected, I think it is different story and relates not to Intellij IDEA preferences, but to async code with running tasks periodically.